# Missing letltxmacro.sty after LaTeX TexStudio installation

Tags: apt, package-management, compiling, latex

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I installed TexStudio via `aptitude`. But when I try to build a document, I get in TexStudio the following error:

```
File `letltxmacro.sty' not found. \RequirePackage{letltxmacro}[2008/06/13]
```

After some Google search, I found that it may belong to the packages `gl2ps` or `libgl2ps*`. However, neither of them is available in my repository:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gl2ps
```

Is it possible to fix this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to the [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=letltxmacro.sty) - you need to install single package for *letltxmacro.sty*:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Comment: That works just fine.